# platform dependent linker flags in bazel (for glut)

Tags: cross-platform, glut, bazel

I am trying to build the c++ app with glut using bazel. It should work on both macos and linux. Now the problem is that on macos it requires passing `"-framework OpenGL", "-framework GLUT"` to linker flags, while on linux I should probably do soemthing like 

`cc_library(
    name = "glut",
    srcs = glob(["local/lib/libglut*.dylib", "lib/libglut*.so"]),
    ...`
 
in glut.BUILD.
So the question is 
1. How to provide platform-dependent linker options to cc_library rules in general? 
2. And in particular how to link to glut in platform-independent way using bazel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the Bazel [select()](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) function. Something like this might work:

```
config_setting(
    name = "linux_x86_64",
    values = {"cpu": "k8"},
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

config_setting(
    name = "darwin_x86_64",
    values = {"cpu": "darwin_x86_64"},
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "glut",
    srcs = select({
        ":darwin_x86_64": [],
        ":linux_x86_64": glob(["local/lib/libglut*.dylib", "lib/libglut*.so"]),
    }),
    linkopts = select({
        ":darwin_x86_64": [
            "-framework OpenGL",
             "-framework GLUT"
        ],
        ":linux_x86_64": [],
    })
    ...
)
```

Dig around in the Bazel github repository, it's got some good real world examples of using select().

Comment: Do I have to pass config setting manually then? Or is there some system introspection?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but with picking the right compiler depending on the platform and @zlalanne's solution didn't work for me. After 2 days of frustration, I finally found the following solution:

```
config_setting (
  name = "darwin",
  constraint_values = [ "@bazel_tools//platforms:osx" ]
)

config_setting (
  name = "windows",
  constraint_values = [ "@bazel_tools//platforms:windows" ]

)
```

I didn't have any need for `linux`, but adding this to your `BUILD` file should work:

```
config_setting (
  name = "linux",
  constraint_values = [ "@bazel_tools//platforms:linux" ]
)
```

Use `":darwin"`, `":windows"` and `":linux"` in your `select`s  and you should have a solution that works.